# Проблема в создании .jar с подключёнными библиотеками

Tags: java

Доброго времени суток!
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: JRE не может найти необходимую библиотеку, хотя она указана в манифесте.

Вот, собственно, манифест:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: jintellitype-1.3.7.jar
Main-Class: yanislavPackage.CloudBufferClient
```

Структура `.jar` файла:

[image: .jre]

И сама ошибка при запуске из консоли:

[image: cmd]

(Ошибка, конечно, связанна с проблемой в нахождении библиотеке: `HotKeyListener` (см. ошибку) идёт первым в импорте, и если поменять его местами, с любым другим любыми импортами классов из этой библиотеки, будет выдаваться соответствующая ошибка)

Может, кто-нибудь сталкивался с подобной проблемой и может мне помочь?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Процитирую [Java SE Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html)

> **Внимание**: Заголовок `Class-Path` в манифесте указывает на классы или JAR файлы в локальной сети, а не на классы и JAR файлы внутри вашего JAR файла или доступные по сети Интернет. Чтобы загрузить классы из JAR файла внутри вашего JAR файла, вам нужно реализовать свой загрузчик классов. Например, если файл `MyJar.jar` содержит внутри `MyUtils.jar`, вы не сможете использовать заголовок `Class-Path` в манифесте файла `MyJar.jar`, что загрузить классы из `MyUtils.jar`.

В общем, так не делают.

- Либо выньте `jintellitype-1.3.7.jar` из вашего JAR файла и положите рядом.
- Либо сделайте, то что называют Uber JAR: слейте содержимое `jintellitype-1.3.7.jar` с вашим JAR. Тут, как упомянул @Etki, вам пригодится *maven-shade-plugin*, если вы используете maven.

Comment: Попробую, спасибо. Странно, что IDEA (которым я этот jar и делал) запихал библиотеку именно внутрь .jar

Comment: IDEA кладет в JAR ровно то, что у вас указано в *Project Structure → Artifacts*